# Don't rollback on cancelling a delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to disable the rollback when a delete query is cancelled? So whatever rows where deleted remain deleted and those not deleted remain there?

I know it breaks ACID, but I made a mistake and it's been 3 hours cancelling that query...and I don't want those rows to be returned. Just so that in the future if this happens again, I won't lock the table if I cancel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly no.

What generally works is to split the delete into batches and run a `WHILE` loop until everything is done:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10000
SELECT top 1 * from sys.objects --prime ROWCOUNT

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM TABLExxx WHERE 1=0 --Delete conditions
END
```

Which will delete 10000<sup>1</sup> rows at a time, so when you cancel you'll only undo a *bit* of your work.

---

<sup>1</sup>10000 is entirely arbitrary - you might want to tune this up or down based on your own data, how long each batch takes and how much work you're happy to lose if you do cancel the script.

Answer (score 1):

I know Sql Server hates cursors, but this seems like a good time to try one. There are several benefits here that would far outweigh the extra processing time:

- You are obviously deleting a very large number of rows. Doing this in one `delete` statement locks probably the entire table for a long time (beyond a certain point, Sql Server will skip row locking and just try to lock the whole table). Deleting the rows one at a time greatly relieves this locking issue.
- You can have the `delete` inside a `try` inside a loop. When an error occurs, write the details to a log table. This will provide you much needed information about what is causing the error so you can figure out how to fix it.
- In the end, you've deleted and committed all the rows that can be deleted and you have a record of just the problematic record(s). It don't get no better than that.
- Cursors are slow? Yeah, but if you had used one, you'd have finished with this long ago.

I know that Sql Server developers consider cursors as **Evil Incarnate**. They are not. They are a tool and like any tool should be enthusiastically used whenever the benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: but how much will the performance of this delete be affected if i have to delete, lets say, 10 million rows? I understand this method will not lock the table and this is great, but will it ever return?

Also i have a job that moves data from table A to B, and the rows im deleting are from table B. With this method the job could work simultaneously with the delete, right?

Comment: I can't tell you with precision how much longer deleting ten million rows will take using a cursor rather than a single delete statement. But I would not be at all surprised to learn that the difference was not all that great. Consider that maintaining locks on millions of rows requires a lot more overhead than maintaining a lock on a single row. Maintaining rollback logs on millions of rows requires a lot more overhead than maintaining a rollback log of a single row. And if there is a problem after deleting a few million rows, the rollback can take *hours* -- and that's not hyperbole.

Comment: Another consideration: when working with individual rows, when a problem occurs (writing or deleting), you have available the exact row that caused the problem. Performing the operation in one swell foop you are faced with trying to find out which of the millions of rows caused the problem. You can be looking at many man-hours of effort. Is that worth a few extra msecs (or even a few extra minutes) of machine time? Worry about performance on those statements that are executed thousands or millions of times a day. Don't worry so much on the once-a-dayers or once-a-monthers. Waste of effort.